# PayPal button return url usage

Tags: security, paypal, paypal-ipn, verification, paypal-buttons

I've got a PayPal html button on my site which should return back to my website with data. My understanding is that there's a return url (with a return method) and a notify url which can do this. The notify url requires an IPN listener which seems like it does a verification check, which is good. I'm not seeing any such verification check for the return url, but it seems like I would want to update the return url based on the result from a verification check in most cases (eg whether the payment was successful). Moreover, I need to know PayPal actually requested the return url to update the db, otherwise this seems to open the door to csrf attacks via return url.

I'm new to PayPal buttons, but I've not seen anything about using notify url and return url together. So what should I being doing in order to resolve these concerns with the return url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To relieve the confusion:

1. The `return_url` just names the page of your webapp you want to return to when the Paypal process is completed. There is also a `cancel_url` which can be used if you want a separate page for user cancels. Returning to the `return_url` *does not mean* that you have the money. It does mean the customer has completed the Paypal transaction, but there could be funding delays and there could be an eventual payment failure, so don't count your chickens yet.
2. The `notify_url` is the URL of a POST handler in your webapp. Not a page. The POST handler should perform the verification step you mentioned, then it should examine the `txn_type` and other variables to see what is being notified. It could be a payment, subscription, termination, payment failure, reversal, cancelled reversal ... Only some of these transaction types mean that you have actually received money from the customer.

> I need to know PayPal actually requested the return url to update the db

Not in the slightest. Take no business actions here.

- On the `return_url` page you should thank them for their business and tell them the action/purchase/subscription etc. that they requested will be finalized once the Paypal payment process is complete.
- The `notify_url` handler should handle all the business actions associated with receiving a payment, getting a reversal, subscription cancellation, etc. The `return_url` and `cancel_url` pages should not do any of that. No money => no action yet.

Comment: Ok. I guess I'd still like to understand the sequence of requests as it seems like either PayPal could kick them off to both pages asynchronously or synchronously depending on their design which may affect design choices on my end.

Comment: Return to `return_url` or `cancel_url` is synchronous: it happens when the user pushes a button. Calling your `notify_url` is asynchronous and could occur many minutes or hours or days later, maybe even never. Your design choices need to take actual business actions via the `notify_url` only, as I stated.

Comment: One last question on this topic. I have my own internal ids that I have to link up to txnIds in notify. The only way I can see that working consistently is if I pass something in the custom field. So at that point the same custom value gets sent on all future requests to the notify url for this transaction? It also seems like if a user leaves the PayPal url before paying by closing the tab, there wouldn't be a transaction, but I'd already be persisting what's essentially an active session id. So how do I know if this session id is inactive without timeout?

Comment: Actually might have found what I was looking for here, which seems to suggest this may not be the right approach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054318/delete-session-variables-when-session-id-is-known-but-not-able-to-start-session