# PayPal checkout options

Tags: session, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, pci-compliance

I've been working on a secure shopping cart and checkout for a website. I'm using PayPal, and I'd read that PCI requirements aren't as much of an issue if we don't store card data on our site, so if possible I'd like to avoid that.

HTML buttons seemed like a promising option, but upon further investigation, it seems like maintaining control of active user sessions may not be possible. Below are my sources that seem to confirm this.

[PayPal button return url usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441562/paypal-button-return-url-usage/39442348?noredirect=1#comment66208366_39442348)
[delete session variables when session id is known but not able to start session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054318/delete-session-variables-when-session-id-is-known-but-not-able-to-start-session)

PayPal payments pro is mentioned in the second post, but I'm wondering if it or anything else meets my 2 design constraints as they're implications for the implementation don't seem to gel very well.

Answer (score 0):

If they are losing session data when returned from PayPal with a standard button then they have something else going wrong.  That should not be happening.

That said, if you're comfortable working with APIs I always recommend Express Checkout and Payments Pro.

If you prefer [REST APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/) you can use that for PayPal payments and direct credit card payments.

If you prefer [NVP / SOAP](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/) you can use the Classic API.

In any case, keeping session data alive won't be an issue, and as you mentioned, as long as you aren't storing any credit card data on your server in log files, in the database, or anywhere then you won't have to worry about PCI compliance.